# export eclipse configurations

Tags: eclipse, import

I have moved recently to a new version of eclipse 3.5 from 3.2.I dont want to recreate all the configurations/settings i did ,is there a way to export /import these settings?please forgive if this is a duplicate question,but i tried to search in SO but couldn get it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/create-new-eclipse-workspace-w

Answer (score 0):

Off top of my head, I think it's under

> File -> Export preferences

Answer (score 0):

File->Export and select preferences - then select what preferences you want to export, and where you want to export them.
You can perform an import just in like the way you performed export. You point to the exported EPF file once you choose File->Import, then choosing "preferences"

Comment: This does not export all the preferences:(
for say i have configured linked resources under 

General > workspace > linked reosurces